# Mecha anime (maybe movie) about a dormant mech's ghost girl choosing a boy to pilot

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I'm looking for an 90s or older anime that aired on Adult Swim back in early 2000s (maybe 2010). I only got to see a little bit of it and am unsure if it was supposed to be a movie or a series.

The short bit I can remember was that a boy (maybe a teenager or young adult) enters this mech even after being told by others that THAT mech in particular wouldn't work for anyone.

The boy attempts to activate the mech anyway and to his surprise it starts up, this is before he gets spooked by what looks like a ghost (maybe blue or all white), a girl. He quickly exits and tells the other workers about it, but they dismiss his concerns as 'you're seeing things'.

Late into the night the boy tries again, gingerly entering the mech, only to encounter the ghost/spirit girl again. Don't know what she says, but she likes him and chooses him and allows him to pilot the machine; she may kiss or hug him, not sure?

The thing is, I'm not sure if she's actually a ghost, an AI spirit, or whatever, but I know she's the reason why he can pilot the mech at all. I think this was before the mech was launched out of the docking station.

- Mech ghost/spirit/maybe ai girl chooses boy pilot
- 90s or older animation
- It was English dubbed at some point
- Aired on Adult Swim early 2000s maybe 2010 (or so)
- gundam-esque
- Maybe in space???

Side note:

- I am 90% sure it is **not** Pilot Candidate, the animation style and scene does not fit memory.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the anime you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Long shot, but Eureka Seven?

Comment: It might have inspired Arpeggio of Blue Steel.